# MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, appveyor

I have not worked with Visual C++ for a long time. Let me know what I'm doing is not right? Please... ((

appveyor.yml:

```
version: '{build}'

environment:
  matrix:
    - APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE: Visual Studio 2017
      platform: x86
      FLAGS: ""
      GENERATOR: Visual Studio 15 2017

    - APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE: Visual Studio 2017
      platform: x64
      FLAGS: ""
      GENERATOR: Visual Studio 15 2017

init:
  - cmake --version
  - msbuild /version

before_build:
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
  - cmake . -G "%GENERATOR%" -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\Libraries\boost_1_67_0

build_script:
  - cmake --build . --config Release --target all
```

Comment: I suppose the cmake command in the `before_build` step fails or you are in the wrong directory. Please try to escape the GENERATOR settings as follows `GENERATOR: 'Visual Studio 15 2017'` (note the single quotes) and output the path before cmake call.

Comment: `cmake --build . --config Release --target ALL_BUILD` Thanks for me, I answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I cannot write YAML in comments. You can replace your `environment.matrix` section with this, should look more compact:

```
image: Visual Studio 2017
platform:
- x86
- x64
environment:
  FLAGS: '""'
  GENERATOR: Visual Studio 15 2017
```